# Maximize Form from differient form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, maximize

Does anyone know how to maximize a form from another form, in c#?

I tried the code below but it won't work:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That should work, what happens?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well two possible problems, either you don't get any form at all, then the solution is to Show the form.

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
form1.Show();
```

But I guess that you already have a form1 loaded somewhere, then you can not use

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

because then you creates a new form that you don't display, remove this line and find a way to pass a reference to `form1` from where it was originally created to the method where the above code is located.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go To Load Form Or Button As View Code and use This Code :

> C#

`this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;`

> I hope it will be useful for you ;)